# Programmatically open a file from Xamarin.Mac solution

Tags: c#, macos, permissions, docx, xamarin.mac

We have a Xamarin.Mac application which has to load/open a DOCX file programmatically from the application.

Can anyone let me know what would be the best way to programmatically open a file from the Xamarin.Mac solution and if this is related to providing special user permissions for the application?

Comment: What have you tried? Is the app sandboxed (required for app store)? 
And what do you mean by 'open'. For basic reading in the data you should be able to use system.io.file and such

Answer (score 1):

You likely want

```
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile (string)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1525235-openfile?language=objc

or

```
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile (string, string)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1524481-openfile?language=objc